# Building a R package specifying the R version

Tags: r, build

I recently upgraded R to version 3.0.0. I wa previously using R.2.15.2, I tried to load [fasttime](http://www.rforge.net/fasttime/files/) that I built previously. Off course it told me that it was build with an old version of R and that I had to do it again.

First let me say that I CANNOT use `update.packages` or `install.packages` (firewall), so I loaded the `.tar.gz` sources and tried `R CMD INSTALL --build fasttime_1.0-0.tar.gz`, this worked but used the old version of `R` I have in my `PATH` (I think as I see R 2.15.2 printed on the screen). Offcourse I cannot change the `PATH`

Question:
How can I tell `R CMD INSTALL` to use `R.3.0.0`, or how can I do otherwise

Comment: Calling `R` searches for `R.exe` in your path. Be explicit about it. `C:/Program Files/R/3.0/bin/x64/R.exe CMD INSTALL...`.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work...`"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.0\bin\x64\R.exe" INSTALL CMD --build fasttime_1.0-0.tar.gz`
'--build' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes. (French for --build is not recognized)

Comment: Damn CMD INSTALL and not INSTALL CMD !!!! Thanks